# Solr Schemaless mode Query to match any word in a [ Text_general] field type

Tags: solr, solrj, solrcloud, solr4

I'm trying to  Search solr query in schemaless mode. but a matching document was not found in the result.

q: i m from india
numResult: 0

q: parapfa551d3aef764ddca9e6e421fe8d50e8:i m from india
numResult: 1

my data(600+) set in solr all fields of document dynamic added using solr schemaless mode. see my solr document.

the first query I tried to run in solr schemaless mode. but numResult get zero.[solr standalone mode query working. but dynamic field not added in solr.]
can I best matching the document found in solr schemaless mode.?

```
  {
        "id":"d9263e11",
        "titleh4cd06d47basdsa6d14ed8838a123":["User _ name"],
        "parapfa551d3aef764ddca9e6e421fe8d50e8":["  My name is XYZ "],
        "parapffe001011d4346ad9ce9edb67b3b85e4":["  i m from USA ...."],
        "_version_":1748577992052834304},
      {
        "id":"d9263e20",
        "titleh4cd06d47b6d14ed883842ae4cedab224":[" User_name "],
        "parap759981766b644e229bda2b0cc5bd0bd9":["  my name is ...."],
        "parapfa551d3aef764ddca9e6e421fe8d50e8":["  i m from INDIA"],
        "_version_":1748577992544616448},
      {
        "id":"d9263e45",
        "titlehdd4a37c0b21e4d9bbd03a56ba0120f01":[" User_name"],
        "parapa2aa4798c7fc44aab5e4f6447c529f83":["my name is  .... "],
        "parap8ee9090e8e054d78b8dc7ff06a7fb702":["  i m from Germany"],
        "_version_":13204902384923489909}
```

I'm trying to best match the document found in solr schemaless mode.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your first query

```
q: i m from india
```

does not have a field specified to search on and therefore Solr will use on a default field (usually `_text_`) when searching. I suspect your index is probably not populating this default field and hence there is no match.

Your second query

```
q: parapfa551d3aef764ddca9e6e421fe8d50e8:i m from india
```

is searching for the string in the `parapfa551d3aef764ddca9e6e421fe8d50e8` field, and in this case the match is found.

You can use [Solr's debugQuery](https://hectorcorrea.com/blog/solr-debugquery/2021-11-11-00001) parameter to see how Solr handles each of these searches on your particular configuration.

Comment: can I do auto-indexed field type in schemaless mode?.
 <field name="parap001fc0f4599749ce9a67174cdcd0b210" type="text"/> i have change to these auto add field to 
 <field name="parap001fc0f4599749ce9a67174cdcd0b210" type="text"  indexed="true" stored="false" multiValued="true"/>